# Create an unique list of multiple arrays inside a subdocument.

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to create an unique list of array values inside a subdocument.

Document:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aee0e3c059638093b69c8b3"),
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "websites" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
            "key" : "website2",
            "url" : "www.xxx.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "php", 
                "python", 
                "java"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("456"),
            "key" : "website2",
            "url" : "www.yyy.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "java",
                "php"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("789"),
            "key" : "website3",
            "url" : "www.zzz.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "java",
                "html",
                "css"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aee0e3c059638093b69c8b3"),
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "unique_tags": [
        "java",
        "php",
        "python",
        "html",
        "css",
    ],
    "websites" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
            "key" : "website2",
            "url" : "www.xxx.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "php", 
                "python", 
                "java"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("456"),
            "key" : "website2",
            "url" : "www.yyy.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "java",
                "php"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("789"),
            "key" : "website3",
            "url" : "www.zzz.com",
            "tags" : [ 
                "java",
                "html",
                "css"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks like Mongo has a `distinct` functionality, but this does not work inside an `aggregate` query (right?!).
Also tried to unwind on `websites.tags` and use the `addToSet` functionality but it also hasn't the right output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            unique_tags: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { 
                        $concatArrays: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$websites",
                                as: "website",
                                in: "$$website.tags"
                            }
                        } 
                    },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $setUnion : ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

To flatten an array of arrays (`websites` -> `tags`) you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/). Then you'll get an array of all tags from all websites. To get only unique values you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) (which drops duplicates).